# spark scala each datasets output as a single row of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdf

I have multiple .nt (NTriples) files in a directory. I want to read each dataset and store it's respective output values in a single row of dataframe.

Let say I have dataset1.nt, dataset2.nt,...,datasetn.nt.
When reading each dataset using following code:

```
val input = "src/main/resources/dataset1.nt"
val triplesRDD = NTripleReader.load(spark, JavaURI.create(input))
//NTripleReader reads .nt file and separates each line of dataset into subject, predicate and object     
/* My code to output number of distinct subjects, predicates and blank subjects in a dataset */
```

Let's say dataset1 is giving following output:

- Number of distinct subjects: xxxx
- Number of distinct predicates: yy
- Number of blank subjects: zzz

Let's say dataset2 is giving following output:

- Number of distinct subjects: aaaaa
- Number of distinct predicates: b
- Number of blank subjects: cc

and so on...

When I am using the following code to read all files in my directory:

```
val input = "src/main/resources/*"
val triplesRDD = NTripleReader.load(spark, JavaURI.create(input))
```

It is giving me following output:

- Number of distinct subjects: xxxx+aaaaa+... // adding all individual values of each dataset
- Number of distinct predicates: yy+b+...
- Number of blank subjects: zzz+cc+...

However, I want my output to be like this:

```
Distinct Subjects | Distinct Predicates | Blank Subjects
xxxx              | yy                  | zzz
aaaaa             | b                   | cc    
...               | ...                 | ...
```

Please let me know how can I achieve my desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the `triplesRDD`? this looks like you copied code from the SANSA project? Or are you using the SANSA RDF API via Maven?

Comment: triplesRDD type is RDD[Triple]. I am using SANSA RDF API via Maven. I didn't copied the code I am just using NTripleReader as I am working on SANSA STACK currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering to my question. I hope this might be helpful for others

```
import java.io.File
//import other necessary packages


object abc {
  var df1: DataFrame = _
  var df2: DataFrame = _         
  var df3: DataFrame = _

  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = 
  {
    //initializing the spark session locally
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
          .master("local[*]")
          .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
          .appName("abc")
          .getOrCreate()

//    creates a list of all files in a directory:
    def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = 
    {
      val path = new File("path/to/directory/")
      if (path.exists && path.isDirectory) 
      {
        path.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
      } 
      else 
      {
        List[File]()
      }
    }

      val files = getListOfFiles("path/to/directory/")
      val input = ""
      for (input <- files)
      {  
      //  println(input)
        val triplesRDD = NTripleReader.load(spark, JavaURI.create(input.toString()))

        /*code to generate dataframe columns value*/

        import spark.implicits._

        if(input == files(0))
        {
            df3 = Seq(
            (column1_value, column2_value, column3_value, column4_value, column5_value, column6_value)
            ).toDF("column1_name", "column2_name", "column3_name", "column4_name", "column5_name", "column6_name")
        } 
        else
        {    
            df1 = Seq(
            (column1_value, column2_value, column3_value, column4_value, column5_value, column6_value)
            ).toDF("column1_name", "column2_name", "column3_name", "column4_name", "column5_name", "column6_name")  
            df2 = df3.union(df1)
            df3 = df2
        }
      }
      df3.show()
// import dataframe to .csv file
          df3.coalesce(1).write
          .option("header", "true")
          .csv("path/to/directory/sample.csv")
          spark.stop
      }
    }
```